# sending emails once a value is met in a column

Tags: excel, vba, email

I presently created a code that will send 1 email to a specific individual once a value is met in a specific cell.

what I need is for the macro to search an entire column (column E) and send out an email (email address found in column D) every time the value is met (in E) but only once per ID number (found in column C)

```
example:
   A        B       C        D                        E      F    G
   John     Smith   123659   john.smith@gmail.com     330    NB   Moncton
   John     Smith   123659   john.smith@gmail.com     330    NB   Shediac
```

so only one email would go out as the value met is 330 and both entries are from the same ID number

this is the code I presently have but it is specific to a cell

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Not Application.Intersect(Range("E2"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = 330 Then
        Call renewalemail
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Sub renewalemail()


Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)


xMailBody = "Hi," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Your registration to the National Transfer Inventory is up for renewal" & vbNewLine & _
            "Every year, you are required to review your selection(s) and renew your registration" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Please refer to the frequently asked questions (FAQ) document for more details (RDIMS# 5757800)" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Thank you"


            On Error Resume Next
With xOutMail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "XXX.ServiceCentre-CentredeService.XXX@gmail.com"
    .To = Sheets("Inventory").Range("D2").Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "RENEWAL NOTIFICATION - National Transfer Inventory / AVIS de RENOUVELLEMENT - Répertoire de Mutation"
    .Body = xMailBody
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set xOutMail = Nothing
Set xOutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

thank you

```
 Sub Cmdrenewal_Click()

   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim r As Range

 Set ws = Worksheets("Inventory")

   With ws


    lr = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For I = lr To 1 Step -1
    If .Cells(I, "S") = 383 Then
    Call renewalemail
    End If

  Next I

  End With

  On Error Resume Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried to make the part where you say *...to search an entire column (column E) and send out an email (email address found in column D) every time the value is met (in E) but only once per ID number ...*

Comment: I was able to do the following (see added code above)....the code searches the sheet and send out an email for every row that meets the criteria (383).....I still need coding that will identify the email address located in column c of that row and send to that address. I would also need that only one email is sent per ID ....so if the individual with ID 3569 has10 rows that meet 383 criteria.....one email is sent using the address in column c advising and not 10 emails

Answer (score 0):

Store the id. There are many ways to do it:

- Store them on a string, separated with "," or ";" or whatever symbol you want, then split it and iterate the Array
- Find how Dictionarys work: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Or simply remove duplicates based on C column.